# Effective way of getting data from a webpage and display them in android app

Tags: android

I want to get data from a webpage to stylize and display them in my android app, is there an effective way to do so?? I've already tried xml parsers but the app becomes extremely slow.

Comment: Put All webpages in Assest folder and open on webview in andorid

Comment: i want the application to be live, if any change happens i want it in the app.

Comment: Use any Html parser in android

Answer (score 1):

I think html parser is effective enough if you want restyle webpage(remove, add something, etc.)

Have you tried JSoup?

[JSoup HTML parser](http://jsoup.org)

> jsoup is a Java library for working with real-world HTML. It provides
>   a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the
>   best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods.
>
> jsoup implements the WHATWG HTML5 specification, and parses HTML to
>   the same DOM as modern browsers do.
>
> ```
> scrape and parse HTML from a URL, file, or string
> find and extract data, using DOM traversal or CSS selectors
> manipulate the HTML elements, attributes, and text
> clean user-submitted content against a safe white-list, to prevent XSS attacks
> output tidy HTML
> ```
>
> jsoup is designed to deal with all varieties of HTML found in the
>   wild; from pristine and validating, to invalid tag-soup; jsoup will
>   create a sensible parse tree.

---

Adding to project:

Download lib

[Latest JSoup jar](http://jsoup.org/download)

Right click on your project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add [external] Jars

Comment: You are welcome.

Adding to project:

Download lib
  http://jsoup.org/download   - 

Right click on your project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add [external] Jars